# handsontable validation part is not working, it is iterating for 26, where as same code is working in other page

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller, handsontable

I'm not able tom understand ,where my code is worng? i have implemented handsontable, everything is working fine expect validation, in validation its is iterating multiple times. But itrating for 25 times

Hi All, I'm not able tom understand ,where my code is worng? i have implemented handsontable, everything is working fine expect validation, in validation its is iterating multiple times. But itrating for 25 times

```
enter code here
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $('#btnValidateSave').on('click',function () {
     debugger;
    $('#HSTable').handsontable('validateCells', function (isPass) {
        if (isPass) {
            SaveData();
            alert("Saving data");
        }
        else {
            alert("Please enter the data in correctformat");
        }
    });
    //$('#HSTable').handsontable('render');
   });

   $('#btnUpload').click(function () {
     upload();

          })

      });


         function upload()
           {
 var formData = new FormData();
 var totalFiles = document.getElementById("UploadFile").files.length;
 for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
     var file = document.getElementById("UploadFile").files[i];
        formData.append("Document", file);
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: "/BulkUpload/UploadFile",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: formData,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function (result) {
            if (result != null) {
                DataBind(result);
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
      });
        }


        function DataBind(result) {

     $("#HSTable").handsontable({
    data: result,
     startRows: 100,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: ["Agent","Invoice No", "Issue Date", "Passanger",
       "Empno", "ProjectCode", "RequestNo", "RequireDate",
       "AirlineName", "AirLineCode", "Ticket", "Locator", "FlightNO",          "DetpDate",
       "ReturnDate", "ServiceClass", "ServiceType", "TravelType", "TripType", "Sector",
       "OrgnDtn", "Region", "BaseFare", "TotalTax", "ServiceFare", "TotalFare", "Remarks"],
    columns: [
       {data: 'Agent'},
       { data:'InvoiceNo' },
       { data: 'IssueDate' },
       {
           data: 'Passenger',

       },
        {
            data: 'EmpNo',

        },
        {
            data: 'ProjectCode',

        },
        {
            data: 'RequestNo',

        },
       { data:'RequireDate'},
       {data:'AirLineName'},
       { data: 'AirLinecode' },
      { data: 'TicketNo' },
      { data: 'Locator' },
      { data: 'FlightNo' },
      { date: 'DepDate' },
      { date: 'ReturnDate' },
     { data: 'ServiceClass' },
     { data: 'ServiceType' },
     { data: 'TravelType' },
     { data: 'tripType' },
     { data: 'Sector'},
     { data: 'OrgDtn' },
     { data: 'Region' },
     { data: 'BaseFare' },
     { data: 'TotalTax' },
     { data: 'ServiceFee' },
     { data: 'TotalFare' },
     { data: 'Remarks' }

    ],
    colWidths: 85,
       });

      }
       var notEmpty=function(value, callback) {
   if (!value || String(value).length === 0) {
         callback(false);

      }
          else {
    callback(true);
}
```

};

```
     var EmailValidator = function (value, callback) {
   if (/.+@@.+/.test(value)) {
    callback(true);
}
else {
    callback(false);
}

           };


   function SaveData() {

var data = [{}];
var $container = document.getElementById('#HSTable');
var colHeaderList = $('#HSTable').handsontable("getColHeader");
var rowHeaderList = $('#HSTable').handsontable("getRowHeader");
var tableData = $('#HSTable').handsontable("getData");
var obj = $('#HSTable').handsontable("getData");

var ObjBulk = [];
debugger;
//for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
for(var i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
      var user = new Object();

   user.Agent = obj[i]["0"];
    user.InvoiceNo = obj[i]["1"];       
    user.IssueDate = obj[i]["2"];
    user.Passenger = obj[i]["3"];
    user.EmpNo = obj[i]["4"];
    user.ProjectCode = obj[i]["5"];
    user.RequestNo = obj[i]["6"];
    user.RequireDate = obj[i]["7"];
    user.AirLineName = obj[i]["8"];
    user.AirLineCode = obj[i]["9"];
    user.TicketNo = obj[i]["10"];
    user.Locator = obj[i]["11"];
    user.FlightNo = obj[i]["12"];
    user.DeptDate = obj[i]["13"];
    user.ReturnDate = obj[i]["14"];
    user.ServiceClass = obj[i]["15"];
    user.ServiceType = obj[i]["16"];
    user.TravelType = obj[i]["17"];
    user.Sector = obj[i]["18"];
    user.OrgDtn = obj[i]["19"];
    user.Region = obj[i]["20"];
    user.BaseFare = obj[i]["21"];
    user.TotalTax = obj[i]["22"];
    user.ServiceFee = obj[i]["23"];
    user.TotalTax = obj[i]["24"];
    user.ServiceFee = obj[i]["25"];
    user.TotalFare = obj[i]["26"];
    user.Remarks = obj[i]["27"];
    ObjBulk.push(user);
    }
//};

       $.ajax({
    url: "/BulkUpload/SaveBulkData",
    type: "POST",  
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "JSON",
    data: JSON.stringify(ObjBulk),
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr) {
        alert(xhr)
    }

      });

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply emailValidator function to column that contains email ids.

for eg:

```
columns: [
      {data: 'id', type: 'numeric'},
      {data: 'name.first'},
      {data: 'name.last'},
      {data: 'ip', validator: ipValidatorRegexp, allowInvalid: true},
      {data: 'email', validator: emailValidator, allowInvalid: false}
    ]
```

You can refer to [**fiddle for demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mazzu/a24zn37j/)

Comment: I'm not using that mail validator field, I'm using NotEmpty  validator for the four column. In Button click event I'm calling Validate function, it is working But It is Iterating 26 times, suppose if i had Give alert windown on for validation true 26 time alert window is coming.

Comment: Alright! You have applied validation on entire handsontable, as a result it iterates through every cell. You need apply validation for that particular column only.

Comment: use afterValidate Callback, it'll call once per row after is validated.

Comment: validateCells(callback): Validates all cells using their validator functions and calls callback when finished. Does not render the view.
If one of cells is invalid, the callback will be fired with 'valid' arguments as false - otherwise it would equal true.

Comment: Try some hacks as: In handsontable JS file, Go to else {
        // resolve callback even if validator function was not found (probably line 1093). Remove :      cellProperties.valid = true; done(cellProperties.valid);  And add: 
     instance._registerTimeout(setTimeout(function() {
         cellProperties.valid = true;
         done(cellProperties.valid);
       }, 0));

Comment: Have a look at links for quick reference: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/933

Comment: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/commit/ee1fa30cb1bb4906665acc414075e2f8143c2bbd